# Is it possible to remove page margins in Indesign, or make the margins apply to a spread as if it were a single page?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm building an app in a hurry, and we're starting the process in InDesign. I won't go into the crazy technicalities that led to this need, but **I need to flow text over two pages as if they were the same page.** Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Obviously I can do this just by stretching a text frame across the two pages - but when I try to flow text through the pages on a grander scale using a master page with that text box, the pre-existing margins interfere and act as unwanted text boxes. **I can't find a way to remove them, or make them stretch across two pages in the same way the text frame can.**

Has anyone got a solution, or is this going to be an arduous case of stretching a frame across every single spread in the document?

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You realize running text over the gutter is **very bad** design, right? Lines, and especially characters, will never align properly when printed.

Comment: Hi Scott - as I said, I'm not printing anything, I'm building **an app**. The prototypes show perfect alignment, so this isn't bad design - for the framework I'm using this is actually a technical requirement. I'm assuming that despite InDesign's supposed "great support for devices" this just isn't possible?

Comment: I'm confused to be honest. An app wouldn't have a gutter or spreads so I don't understand the need for them in Indesign. If you want a double size spread in the app set the page size to the spread size. In any event, the best you can do with Indesign is to set facing pages, then the inside margin to zero.

Comment: Sounds like a skeuomorphic design pattern

Comment: Yup, Horatio's exactly right - the app needs spreads and margins because it has a "page turn" effect so that it feels in some way like a printed book - a bit like issuu.com. Think the solution has been posted now, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, for this bit:

> ...the pre-existing margins interfere and act as unwanted text boxes.
>   I can't find a way to remove them

Sounds like `Primary text frame` was ticked when you created the document.

Normally, margins are just margins - innocent guidelines that don't get in the way. The `Primary text frame` tick box turns them into default text frames. Looks like it's ticked by default if you choose 'Digital publishing'.

---

As for the other problem, there's two parts. First, getting a text frame across each spread. It's easy, and it sounds like you might already have figured it out, but here's the steps anyway:

- Create a 2-page spread master (page window > New Master)
- Stretch the text box across it
- When adding new pages, add them two at a time using this master
- (the more obscure bit) To get at and use the text frame from the master page on each page, **'override'** it (drag it from the master to the page) by selecting it **while holding `shift` and `cmd/ctrl`**. Otherwise it treats it as purely part of the background and won't let you select or edit it.

---

The harder part is getting them to all link together into one story (assuming you want to do this).

If you do need this, [read up on the various auto flow options](http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/threading-text.html#flow_text_manually_or_automatically) and see what works for your case. They're all a bit quirky, so the best approach depends on personal preference and the fine detail of your workflow. Might turn out to be easier to just link them manually.

Comment: one thing you can do is to set up two masters: A = normal spread, B = spread with text box across the spread.